# Unable to split, append and sort in Python

Tags: python

I am very new to programming and started with Python.I have to read strings from an external file and split the line into a list of words using the split() method. The program should build a list of words. For each word on each line i have to check to see if the word is already in the list and if not append it to the list. When the program completes, sort and print the resulting words in alphabetical order.
Following is the program i wrote.

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")

fh = open(fname)

wordlist = list()

for lines in fh:
    line = lines.split()
    wordlist.append(line)

for word in wordlist:
    word.sort()
    print word
```

But there is some error and i am unable to find.

Comment: Could you add the stack trace of your error?

Comment: "There is some error" is a useless problem description.

Comment: working fine for me, just add `fh.close()` at the end of first for loop or use with context manager

Comment: pramod is right

Comment: The description says "For each word on each line i have to check to see if the word is already in the list and if not append it to the list. ". But your code doesn't test if the word is already in the list. So you need to loop over each word in the list returned by `lines.split()` and see if it's in `wordlist` before appending that word to `wordlist`. FWIW, there's actually a more efficient way to do this (using a set of words for `wordlist`), but your assignment is to do it the slow way.

Answer (score 0):

Like what others have already commented on the question, line numbers indicated in error messages give us a very good idea where Python has encountered an error.

I haven't run your code, but do a check on your following lines:

```
for lines in fh:
line = lines.split()
```

The line after a for loop must be indented. It could be an error when you composed your post, but worth a check.

It should read:

```
for lines in fh:
    line = lines.split()
```